# "Syntax error on token "module", interface expected"

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, module

this bit of code gives me the error message: "Syntax error on token "module", interface expected. Does anyone know why?

```
module TeaThiever{
}
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @Lucas Wedel , As VLAZ mentioned, Java is not the same language as JavaScript, it is therefore difficult to know how to help you.

Comment: If this is Java what is the file name? Only 'module-info.java' can contain a module statement.

Comment: Its java, just ran out of tags to use. The file name is "module-info.java", and only contains the lines of code in the original question

Comment: You don't have to use all 5 tags and adding javascript is just plain wrong.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post if i didn't add all 5, maybe because it is my first post

Comment: In the Java Compiler page of the project properties what do you have for the 'Compiler compliance level'? It needs to be at least Java 9 to use a module-info.java

Comment: I added Java 9 from the library and it fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The `module` statement is only valid in a `module-info.java` file and it must be used with Java 9 or above.

In Eclipse set the 'Compiler compliance level' on the project 'Java Compiler' properties page to be Java 9 or above (you also need to have a suitable Java installed).

Answer (score 0):

Modules were added in Java 9. You need to update your JDK. I recommend you use Java 11.

Project -> Propertes -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Lbrary -> JRE System Library -> Execution environment -> JavaSE-11(jre).